# How can I get this look on my welcome screen? flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to have a welcome screen like this:
[image: Here is the image]

I have all the lines from the bottom and the orange and blue bubbles as asset images. How can I stack them all together and then use Text() widget for the writing part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stack widget to stack its children if that answers your question:

```
Stack(
   children: [
       your_images_here,
       your_text_here,
   ],
);
```

Comment: Can you give me the full code, I've already tried to use Stack, but when I use positioned widget to position my images. The images will vanish.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using stack by using the image property in container decoration.

```dart
 Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/bg.png',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )),
          child: Column(
          children: [
          // your text widgets
          ])
        ),
```

Comment: But here I have three Images that should be stacked all to gether, I don't have only one image to use an ImageProvider.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer gave me an idea. I'll post the answer in the answers later on.

Answer (score 0):

So I had three images, and I couldn't use Imageprovider to use it as a background image of my main Container(). But, I decided to make a difference in my design by wrapping them all together using adobe photoshop and getting one image instead of three so that I can use ImageProvider instead of a stack. Then I used Decoration image and made the image the background of my page.